# What is the proper exception to throw if an ODBC driver cannot be found

Tags: .net, exception, odbc

I have the following code that searches for installed Microsoft Access drivers:

```
var odbcRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
    "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBCINST.INI\\ODBC Drivers", false);
var drivers = new List<string>(odbcRegKey.GetSubKeyNames());
if (drivers.Contains("Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)"))
{
    MicrosoftAccessProvider = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)";
}
else if (drivers.Contains("Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)"))
{
    MicrosoftAccessProvider = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)";
}
else
{
    //TODO: Throw some kind of excception
}
```

What is the proper exception to throw if it cannot find the ODBC driver? There are no public constructors for [`OdbcException()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcexception.aspx)

Comment: We need more context - is this in a library, or the startup of an application, or something else? Is it definitely an *error* for no Access drivers to be installed?

Comment: Jon, I have a 32 bit Access driver. The problem is getting this to run in a 64 bit .NET process. That was not possible until the release of Office 2010 64 bit and the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255). For more context, see [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223334/what-is-the-right-syntax-for-calling-compact-db-and-repair-db-with-aceodbc-dll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, InvalidOperationException is my go-to choice. If it's something configurable (perhaps being able to use something other than Access), consider ConfigurationException as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty rare for it to make sense to try to continue running a program in cases like this.  Whatever code catches this exception won't know how to install the provider either.  MessageBox.Show() and Environment.Exit() is then appropriate.  Only ever consider throwing an exception if the program can limp along without a dbase.

Comment: Whoa...what? MessageBox.Show? What if this is in library code? Or for a command line app? Or an ASP.NET application? Exceptions aren't (only) used because the program can possibly limp along - but to defer error handling to a higher layer, which can usually make much better decisions about if/how to handle.

Comment: Whoa, where did you get this info?

Comment: I agree Mark. BTW this code is for a SQL Query runner for Microsoft Acccess and [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/), [PlaneDisaster.NET](http://plane-disaster.sourceforge.net/). It is in a separate DB  access class, and in the end a MessageBox.Show() displays the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually throw like this:

```
throw new NotSupportedException("ODBC Driver not found!");
```

Comment: That exception is intended for derived classes that do not implement all the functionality of a base class. (Which generally means that they violate the Liskov Substitution Principle, incidentally.)

Comment: right, but what other kind of Exception can he throw if the ODBCException exposes not ctor?

Comment: Offhand I'd go with InvalidOperationException as @Mark Brackett suggested.